Migrate from VMware Cloud Director to Azure
I currently have a 300GB CentOS 7.9 VM in a VMware Cloud Director environment (vendor private cloud) and I'm looking to do a "lift & shift" to Azure.
I would like to know if anybody tried to do a migration from a VCD environment to Azure. What was the approach, what were the problems?
I've been searching and searching but can't seem to find any "threads" / "experiences" / "issues" on such a migration. There are a couple of old questions here and there but no real experience from what I can see. , I did found this: https://www.netiq.com/documentation/platespin-migrate-12-3/migrate-user/data/reqts-c2c-vcloud2azure.html
It's true that there is a lot of information on migrating from a VMware ESXi (with vCenter) environment to Azure, but this means that I would have to build a new VMware environment in my vendor's datacenter using some hardware, then migrate my VM from VCD to my new VMware environment, AND from there do the Azure "lift & shift" migration.
While doing this might look like a logical thing to do (in my opinion to simply play it safe), I would have to shutdown that VM for a couple of hours AND i would lose the backup solution that VCD is currently offering.
I'm also considering a direct rebuild in Azure, but I estimate this would take me 5 times more because of how old this application is. AND YES, in order to respect "IT Traditions", there is no documentation for it.
If I'm going to do a rebuild, I might as well go directly for an upgrade. This is my long term goal, but, for better security / development speed / etc., I need the old vm to be in the same location as the "new environment" (the upgrade would involve using azure services and not a simple vm).
So any ideas, any experiences are welcomed.
Thank you!
